# Test if object exists or not?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, null

```
Foo*foo1;

foo1=[[Foo alloc]init];
```

After release, object `foo1` still points to some memory but the object doesn't exist. I want to do something like this:

```
if (foo1)
{
    doSomething;
}
```

I cannot assign a `nil` because maybe this object exists and maybe I will get a leak if assign it to `nil`.

How can I get to know whether object exists or not?

Comment: Once you release the object you shouldn't need to worry about if it exists or not. The memory allocation is open for reuse by another object at anytime so even if you did check that memory location for an existing object you are going to get back misleading information. What problem are you trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: I have a viewcontroller1 which pushes another viewcontorller2. When i filled up a data from viewcontorller2 i wanna assign it to viewcontorller1. To do that i'm using ViewWillAppear method. And i'm checking if (viewcontorller2) {do something}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you release an object, you should set your pointer to nil. In your case:

```
Foo *foo1 = [[Foo alloc] init];

... doing stuff with foo1 ...

[foo1 release], foo1 = nil;
```

The assignment of `foo1 = nil` does not modify the object in any way. It clears your *pointer* to the object. Since you have released your retain on the object, obviously you do not care about it any more, and so you should clear your pointer to it.

Comment: Setting the pointer to nil is more of a personal preference, correct? I haven't seen this as a requirement in any documentation.  I understand the idea/reasoning behind it but in no way is it required, am I wrong?

Comment: It is not required. It is a common practice among C and ObjC developers to avoid crashes. It is a bad idea to have pointers around that reference invalid memory. Kind of like leaving tacks all over your bedroom floor with the assumption that you'll remember where it's safe to walk late at night.

Answer (score -1):

When an object has been released, its *retainCount* is 0.

Comment: If you send message [foo1 retainCount] it will  cause an error "Message sent to deallocated instance"

Comment: As ever, using `retainCount` is almost always a bad idea. In addition, as mentioned, it can't even be called here.

Comment: When an object is deallocated, it *has* no retainCount.

Comment: You are right, I had a wrong understanding of the `retainCount`. My apologies.